# ‘va_start’ used in function with fixed args va_start(ap, flags);

Tags: c++

This seemingly simple code snipets is giving me an error i cant figure out:

The error message is: `‘va_start’ used in function with fixed args
   va_start(ap, flags);`

```
static inline int sgx_wrapper_open64(const char *pathname, int  flags,unsigned int mode) {
   va_list ap; 
   va_start(ap, flags); 
   if (flags & O_CREAT)
      mode = va_arg(ap, mode_t); 
   else
      mode = 0777;
   va_end(ap);  
   int retval;
   ocall_open2(&retval, pathname, flags, mode);
   return retval;
}
```

Comment: There are so many problems in this code that it's impossible to say anything meaningful about it. Edit the question to say what this function is supposed to do, and be sure to include what those arguments are supposed to mean and what the returned value is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`va_start`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start) (and all other [variadic helper "functions"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic)) can only be used in functions where the argument list ends in an elipsis `...`.

If you can, then you could modify the function like

```
static inline int sgx_wrapper_open64(const char *pathname, int flags, ...)
{
    va_list ap; 
    va_start(ap, flags); 
    mode_t mode;

    if (flags & O_CREAT)
        mode = va_arg(ap, mode_t); 
    else
        mode = 0777;

    va_end(ap);     

    int retval;
    ocall_open2(&retval, pathname, flags, mode);
    return retval;
}
```

Note especially the change of the function argument list, and the addition of the local variable `mode`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message "‘va_start’ used in function with fixed args" is self-explanatory. Your function has a fixed list of arguments. `va_start` can only be used in a function with a variadic argument list, meaning it ends with ellipsis, such as:

```
static inline int sgx_wrapper_open64(const char *pathname, int flags, ...)
```

Comment: it is self explanatory... now that you said it..thanks

Comment: It would also have been self-explanatory had you simply read the freakin' documentation, @ijuio!